# Problem with detect IP Layer When Pcap file have several Ethernet

Tags: pcap, libpcap, pcapplusplus

I use the latest version of pcapplusplus(23.09). I have a pcap file that each frame has several Ethernet, like the below image:
[image]

I can't find the IP packet with the following commands. I think pcap can't find the second Ethernet.

```
if (parsedPacket.isPacketOfType(pcpp::IPv4) || parsedPacket.isPacketOfType(pcpp::IPv6)) {....}
```

The pcapplusplus also does not find the second Ethernet.

Comment: I think this is because of the "PW Ethernet Control Word" which is a protocol PcapPlusPlus doesn't yet know how to parse

Comment: Thx, How I can add the parser for this protocol to libpcapplusplus?